# hi i tried to check internet connectivity on my app but i have this exception and i use internet permission only

Tags: android

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10175 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

ConnectivityManager checking = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] info = checking.getAllNetworkInfo();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (info[i] != null && info[1].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"not connected :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say that you only use internet permission. ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is a different permission that is needed for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you specify the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in your android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Also, if you plan on using internet access in your app you should also specify the INTERNET permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```